# ASP.NET Core WebAPi, TestHost and [FromBody] parameters for Integration Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, asp.net-core-testhost

I've got an ASP.NET core WebAPI project that is already in use and i want to start integration tests for automation.

The controllers have nothing else than basic:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string req)
{
    var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTO>(req);
    this.service.Create(dto);
    return Json(dto.Id);
}
```

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost for creating the client and server to run the integration testing, bu then when i want to send the payload over the client the controller on the WebApi does not found the parameter mark as [FromBody]. I have already tested on postman sending an string on the body of the post method and is working right, so, what I'm doing wrong?

```
[Fact]
public async Task Execute()
{
    // Act
    var dto = new DTO() { Field1 = "Filed1" ...};

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);

    HttpContent payload = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/sample", payload);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: You need to use a properly configured Test server and create a client that will allow you to do in-memory integration test